# Can i reserve EC2 instance hourly based to save cost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-reserved-instances

I have more than 20 servers in one AWS region. But these instances are scheduled based. Each instance will run 12 hours per day. So all ec2 instance will be running more than 7000 hours per month. I have searched lot of documents, but i didn't get any solutions. Is it possible to reserve all instance as hourly based? If i'm wrong then please correct me. Can any one please advise on this?

Comment: My understanding about scheduled reserved instances is that its applied per instance basis if thats what you are asking

Comment: What features of the "Reservation" do you want? Is it just the pricing discount, or do you also want to "reserve capacity" in case there are constraints on available capacity? How do you schedule/launch your servers to run 12 hours per day?

Comment: I just want pricing discount.  I just using lambda function to start and stop all instances